# Example of SemaphorSlim where maxCount is actually useful

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, semaphore

I'm having trouble coming-up with a semi-realistic scenario/use-case for where `SemaphorSlim`'s `maxCount` parameter is a needed feature.  It seems to me that the typical use case for `SemaphorSlim` is to limit concurrent access to some resources, expressed as "I only want X threads to be able to execute method Xyz() concurrently".  The way I think about this capability is that threads are allowed to enter Xyz() until all "slots" are allocated, and then all other threads wait.  When one "slot" opens up, one of the waiting threads is allowed to occupy or check-out that slot and go ahead executing Xyz().  *Someone* is responsible for calling `Wait` and `Release`.  The most straight-forward way to do this is to have the threads themself call `Wait` before calling Xyz() and then call `Release` after they are finished calling Xyz().

So is `maxCount` simply a feature to guard against bad code?  If you've coded your try/finally properly and you can guarantee that any thread that `Wait`s will `Release`, then it's impossible `CurrentCount` to exceed the initial count.

The documentation for `maxCount` implies that somehow you would call `Release` more times than `Wait` and that you want the system to throw if that happens too much.  I can't think of a good use-case for this.

Comment: I think yes. If you call `new SS(1234)` that sets max count to `int.MaxValue`. It certainly is an optional feature.

Comment: Pretty much. I find `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` extremely useful in non-trivial async scenarios where mutex semantics are required. In these cases `maxCount` allows to catch bugs before they have the chance to do any real damage.

Comment: Reflector shows that max count is only used once in Release for `if (maxCountExceeded) throw ...;`.

Comment: There are just not a lot of ways that the OS or .NET can help a programmer when he uses a sync object incorrectly.  But sure, maxcount is quite useful to detect when the number of Release() calls exceeds the number of WaitOne() calls, very hard to diagnose otherwise.  Getting it wrong the other way around is easy to diagnose, the program deadlocks.  Mutex has a diagnostic feature as well, bombs when the owner thread of the mutex terminates without calling ReleaseMutex().

Comment: all - thanks!  @HansPassant - feel free to post your comment as the answer.